# How to override addtocart.phtml for all type of product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento-2.0.7

I have done this but my code is not working for all types of product.

**layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>  

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

**Template**

```
<?php

?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Custom Input Field -->
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="remarks"
                id="remarks"
                maxlength="255"
                placeholder="Please enter your name"
            />
        </div>
        <!-- Custom Input Field -->
        <br>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can show us your folder structure?

Comment: please show your layout full path?

Comment: I didn't get you? Means

Answer (score 7):

Use following code in your module's `catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`product.info.addtocart` is used for simple products, and `product.info.addtocart.additional` is used for configurable products.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `<action>` method is deprecated and advised against in the Dev Docs I thought I'd provide the right way to do this.

This is quoted from the Dev Docs:

**Example 1:**

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" template="%Namespace_Module::new_template.phtml%"/>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Namespace_Module::new_template.phtml%</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

*Source: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#set_template*

**Explanation:**

The trick here is to look in the original module's layout XML to see which method to use.

The `product.info.addtocart` (Simple Products) and `product.info.addtocart.additional` (Configurable Products) are defined in `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` as follows:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" `name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

And:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

So the right way to override the template file in a module is **example 1**, or:

`Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- Simple Products -->
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Namespace_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml" />

            <!-- Configurable Products -->
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" template="Namespace_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this is helpful for someone.

Answer (score 3):

Try to follow code `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Still This layout is not working for all type of products

Comment: are you try to remove `layout="1column"` in your xml file ?

Comment: I'm trying to remove this **<referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>**

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick for me. Why does `product.info.addtocart.additional` work, but `product.info.addtocart` doesn't? What's the difference and why do they exist?